# sas load into Teradata Date format

Tags: date, sas, format, loading, teradata

I am having an issue when loading SAS dates into Teradata. The date format in SAS was '01Jan2017'D, and after loading the dates in the teradata would show a string of number like 23050, but not in a date format. And I used put function before loading to change the format in SAS and also after loading I used cast date format function in Teradata, but neither of them worked.

Does anybody have the solution for this?

Thanks a lot for answering!

Comment: Try it without the put function.  I usually don't have to do anything special to load SAS dates unless the date field is actually not a date.  Of course, I suppose it depends on exactly what method you are using to load the data

Comment: Can you post detailed example of how you created the SAS variable and how you loaded it into Teradata?  Keep it to the minimal example that you can use to recreate the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using SAS/Access to Teradata? If so it should automatically define the variable as a date in Teradata.  Let's make a little table in SAS.  Note that attaching a valid SAS date format is critical for SAS to understand that your variable has date values.

```
data have ;
  mydate = '01JAN2017'd;
  format mydate date9. ;
run;
```

Now let's upload it to a new teradata table.

```
libname td teradata ..... ;
data td.mytable ;
  set have;
run;
```

Now let's read it back and see what is in it.

```
proc print data=td.mytable;
run;
```

Now if you have already loaded a lot of data into Teradata and the values look like the integer number of days since 1/1/1960, which is how SAS stores dates internally, then it is an easy calculation in Teradata to convert that to a date.  Just add it back to date '1960-01-01'.  Try running this query on your TD server.

```
select DATE '2017-01-01' date1, date '1960-01-01' + 20820 date2
```

Both DATE1 and DATE2 should be the same.